# iOS App Backend Provider

Tags: ios, backend, filesize

I've recently submitted my iOS Quiz app to Apple but noticed that the file size for the app is pretty big (about 150 MB).  Users would need to be connected to wifi in order to download it per Apple's rules.  My quiz app is set up so users are given 4 choices and shown an image and must guess the correct answer from the image shown to them.  How would I minimize the file size for my app so that it isn't so large?  Is there a way I can host the images on a server without losing the functionality of my app?  I heard of something like Backend Services but know nothing about it.  If anyone can guide me in the right direction that would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Did you use imageoptim or some other optimizer to make your images as small as possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out a free back end service like [Parse](http://parse.com/), it could do the trick for you, especially because you dont have a lot (besides images I guess) that'll be on the server side.

[This also helped me start with using it.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/98831/parse-tutorial-getting-started-web-backends)

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have all the quiz data (questions and images) within your app bundle?

You can shrink it next to nothing if you move all your questions and images to a backend server and serve the questions and images (links) using simple JSON Structure.

You can build your own backend (Java/PHP/etc..) or look into using Parse.

Answer (score 0):

1. use JPEG images whenever possible. PNGs costs more space. Do not place jpeg to xcassets, since they will be converted to PNGs. If your pictures should be transparent - it is better to use [Webp](https://github.com/seanooi/iOS-WebP) or [JPNG](https://github.com/nicklockwood/JPNG) format.
2. You may use CloudKit to host your data in a public database. You won't need any backend knowledge to do that. [This](http://nshipster.com/cloudkit/) tutorial will help you understand the basics. WWDC videos covers some more, i suggest you to look at [WWDC 2014, Introducing CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#208) and [WWDC 2015, CloudKit Tips and Tricks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=715).